# Fisher information for Poisson model

Tags: r, self-study, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression, fisher-information

Assuming the data structure given below,

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{l|l}
  y & x \\ \hline \hline
  y_{1} & x_{1} \\
  y_{2} & x_{2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots \\
  y_{n} & x_{n} \\  
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Suppose we want to fit a Poisson regression model such that $y_{i} \sim \text{Pois}(\mu_{i})$ for $i=1,2\ldots,n$.

where: $\mu_{i} = e^{\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i}}$

The Fisher information can be found by:

$$ I(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu_{i}x_{i}x_{i}^{T} $$

Supposing we have the MLEs ($\hat{\beta}_{0}$ and $\hat{\beta}_{1}$) for $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_{1}$, from the above, we should be able to find the Fisher information for both model parameters at the maximum:

$$ I(\hat{\beta}) = \begin{bmatrix} I_{11} & I_{12} \\ I_{21} & I_{22} \end{bmatrix} $$.

I have the data and the resulting Fisher information matrix corresponding to the model above; however, when I try to code the Fisher information from the above manually, my result for the Fisher information differs from correct result.

I have included the a snippet of R code. Perhaps somebody could tell me if the following code will achieve the Fisher information matrix based on the above model specification; or, more generally, if the model specification is correct.

```
mu <- rep(0, n) # Initialize data structure for mu vector.
    for (i in 1:n) {
          # Assign values to mu vector.
        mu[i] <- exp(beta[1]+(beta[2]*x[i,1:2])) 
    }

  # Initialize Fisher information matrix.
infor <- matrix(rep(0, 4), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2, ncol=2) 
for (i in 1:n) {
    temp_matrix <- mu[i]*x[i,1:2]%*%t(x[i,1:2]) # Hold current index value.
    infor <- infor + temp_matrix # Sum to Fisher information matrix.
}

print(infor)
```

**NOTE:**

- Even though there is only one independent variable ($x$), I have augmented the matrix with a column of ones corresponding to the intercept parameter ($\beta_{0}$), as is usually the case with normal regression. Therefore, the independent (design) matrix is of the form:

$$ X = 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_{1,2} \\ 1 & x_{2,2} \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_{n,2} 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Hence each row `i` iterates across `x[i,1:2]`. Should this column be included?

- In the preceding R code, it is assumed that data structures and values not initialized and/or assigned explicitly in the code have been previously initialized and/or assigned.
- Furthermore, the code is designed to be explicit, not efficient.

Comment: Is this for some subject? If so, please add the `self-study` tag. ("Is there a bug in this code" questions are generally off topic on CV.) Yes, if the constant term is in your model, it should appear in your design matrix.

Comment: It's hard to make sense of the snippet, because the first `for` loop does not appear to correspond with the equations. You appear to be trying to assign a *2-vector* `exp(beta[1]+(beta[2]*x[i,1:2]))` to a value `mu[i]` that ought to be a single number. Your "note" is even more confusing: what does it mean for a row to "iterate across `x[i,1:2]`"? Your formulas begin by defining `x` to be a (column) *vector* with a single index, not a matrix with two indices.